# Partial sums and subtotals with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to achieve a table with subtotals as shown [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#pivot), but <del>either that code doesn't work with the latest pandas version (0.18.1) or the example is wrong</del> for multiple columns instead of one. [My code here](http://pastebin.com/B8MZwSUq) results in the following table

```
                                                                   2014    2015    2016
project__name person__username activity__name    issue__subject                        
Influenster   employee1        Development                        161.0   122.0   104.0
                                                 Fix bug           22.0     0.0     0.0
                                                 Refactor view      0.0     7.0     0.0
                               Quality assurance                  172.0   158.0   161.0
              employee2        Development                        119.0   137.0   155.0
                               Quality assurance                  193.0   186.0   205.0
              employee3        Development       Refactor view      0.0     0.0     1.0
Profit tools  employee1        Development                        177.0   136.0   216.0
                               Quality assurance                  162.0   122.0   182.0
              employee2        Development                        154.0   168.0   124.0
                               Quality assurance                  130.0   183.0   192.0
                                                 Fix bug           22.0     0.0     0.0
All                                                              1312.0  1219.0  1340.0
```

and my desired output would be something like:

```
                                                                   2014    2015    2016
project__name person__username activity__name    issue__subject                        
Influenster   employee1        Development                        161.0   122.0   104.0
                                                 Fix bug           22.0     0.0     0.0
                                                 Refactor view      0.0     7.0     0.0
                                                 Total              xxx     xxx     xxx
                               Quality assurance                  172.0   158.0   161.0
                                                 Total              xxx     xxx     xxx
                               Total                                xxx     xxx     xxx
              employee2        Development                        119.0   137.0   155.0
                                                 Total              xxx     xxx     xxx
                               Quality assurance                  193.0   186.0   205.0
                                                 Total              xxx     xxx     xxx
                               Total                                xxx     xxx     xxx
              employee3        Development       Refactor view      0.0     0.0     1.0
                                                 Total              xxx     xxx     xxx
                               Total                                xxx     xxx     xxx
              Total                                                 xxx     xxx     xxx
Profit tools  employee1        Development                        177.0   136.0   216.0
                                                 Total              xxx     xxx     xxx
                               Quality assurance                  162.0   122.0   182.0
                                                 Total              xxx     xxx     xxx
                               Total                                xxx     xxx     xxx
              employee2        Development                        154.0   168.0   124.0
                                                 Total              xxx     xxx     xxx
                               Quality assurance                  130.0   183.0   192.0
                                                 Fix bug           22.0     0.0     0.0
                                                 Total              xxx     xxx     xxx
                               Total                                xxx     xxx     xxx
              Total                                                 xxx     xxx     xxx
All                                                              1312.0  1219.0  1340.0
```

Any help on how to achieve this is appreciated.

Comment: Code in docs does work, however, you need to use `pt.stack()` and include a columns value in pivot_table, `columns=['issue__subject]` in dataframe but Totals will not show for all levels of grouping, only per columns value.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. Code effectively works, I was just invoking stack() on the table thinking it mutated the object instead of returning a new one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Recursive `groupby` and `apply`

```
def append_tot(df):
    if hasattr(df, 'name') and df.name is not None:
        xs = df.xs(df.name)
    else:
        xs = df
    gb = xs.groupby(level=0)
    n = xs.index.nlevels
    name = tuple('Total' if i == 0 else '' for i in range(n))
    tot = gb.sum().sum().rename(name).to_frame().T
    if n > 1:
        sm = gb.apply(append_tot)
    else:
        sm = gb.sum()
    return pd.concat([sm, tot])

fields = ['project__name', 'person__username',
          'activity__name', 'issue__subject']
append_tot(df.set_index(fields))
```

[image]

(corrected typo in recursive function call)

Comment: for rename statement I get TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable error. is it related to pandas version?

Comment: `append_tot3` not found

Comment: Not bad, not bad at all! Didn't quite work for me right out of the box, but wrestled it into submission. Awesome concept!

Answer (score 2):

Consider running three level pivot_tables with stack and concatenate them for a final groupby object. As mentioned, the docs does work if you see the use of `.stack()` on the corresponding pivot_table columns value:

```
# ISSUE_SUBJECT PIVOT
pt1 = pd.pivot_table(data=df, values=['2014', '2015', '2016'], 
                     columns=['issue__subject'], aggfunc=np.sum, 
                     index=['project__name', 'person__username', 'activity__name'], 
                     margins=True, margins_name = 'Total')    
pt1 = pt1.stack().reset_index()

# ACTIVITY_NAME PIVOT
pt2 = pd.pivot_table(data=df, values=['2014', '2015', '2016'], 
                     columns=['activity__name'], aggfunc=np.sum, 
                     index=['project__name', 'person__username'], 
                     margins=True, margins_name = 'Total' )    
pt2 = pt2.stack().reset_index()

# PERSON_USERNAME PIVOT
pt3 = pd.pivot_table(data=df, values=['2014', '2015', '2016'],        
                     columns=['person__username'], 
                     aggfunc=np.sum, index=['project__name'],
                     margins=True, margins_name = 'Total')    
pt3 = pt3.stack().reset_index()

# CONCATENATE ALL THREE
gdf = pd.concat([pt1, 
                 pt2[(pt2['project__name']=='Total') | 
                     (pt2['activity__name']=='Total')],
                 pt3[(pt3['project__name']=='Total') |
                     (pt3['person__username']=='Total')]]).reset_index(drop=True)

# REPLACE NaNS IN COLUMN
gdf = gdf.apply(lambda x: np.where(pd.isnull(x), '', x), axis=1)

# FINAL GROUPBY (A COUNT USED TO RENDER GROUPBY)
gdf = gdf.groupby(['project__name', 'person__username',
                   'activity__name', 'issue__subject',
                   '2014', '2015', '2016']).agg(len)
```

**Output**

```
project__name  person__username  activity__name     issue__subject  2014    2015    2016  
Influenster    Total                                                667.0   610.0   626.0     1
               employee1         Development                        161.0   122.0   104.0     1
                                                    Fix bug         22.0    0.0     0.0       1
                                                    Refactor view   0.0     7.0     0.0       1
                                                    Total           183.0   129.0   104.0     1
                                 Quality assurance                  172.0   158.0   161.0     1
                                                    Total           172.0   158.0   161.0     1
                                 Total                              355.0   287.0   265.0     1
               employee2         Development                        119.0   137.0   155.0     1
                                                    Total           119.0   137.0   155.0     1
                                 Quality assurance                  193.0   186.0   205.0     1
                                                    Total           193.0   186.0   205.0     1
                                 Total                              312.0   323.0   360.0     1
               employee3         Development        Refactor view   0.0     0.0     1.0       1
                                                    Total           0.0     0.0     1.0       1
                                 Total                              0.0     0.0     1.0       1
Profit tools   Total                                                645.0   609.0   714.0     1
               employee1         Development                        177.0   136.0   216.0     1
                                                    Total           177.0   136.0   216.0     1
                                 Quality assurance                  162.0   122.0   182.0     1
                                                    Total           162.0   122.0   182.0     1
                                 Total                              339.0   258.0   398.0     1
               employee2         Development                        154.0   168.0   124.0     1
                                                    Total           154.0   168.0   124.0     1
                                 Quality assurance                  130.0   183.0   192.0     1
                                                    Fix bug         22.0    0.0     0.0       1
                                                    Total           152.0   183.0   192.0     1
                                 Total                              306.0   351.0   316.0     1
Total                                                               1268.0  1212.0  1339.0    1
                                                    Fix bug         44.0    0.0     0.0       1
                                                    Refactor view   0.0     7.0     1.0       1
                                                    Total           1312.0  1219.0  1340.0    1
                                 Development                        633.0   570.0   600.0     1
                                 Quality assurance                  679.0   649.0   740.0     1
                                 Total                              1312.0  1219.0  1340.0    1
               Total                                                1312.0  1219.0  1340.0    1
               employee1                                            694.0   545.0   663.0     1
               employee2                                            618.0   674.0   676.0     1
               employee3                                            0.0     0.0     1.0       1
```