# pandas: add a total row for each subgroup when groupby (especially for non-additive method such as `nunique`)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

It's easy to produces multi-level groupby result like this

```
                Max Speed
Animal Type
Falcon Captive      390.0
       Wild         350.0
Parrot Captive       30.0
       Wild          20.0
```

The code would look like `df.groupby(['animal', 'type'])['speed'].max()`

However, if I want to add a total row to each subgroup, to produce something like this

```
                Max Speed
Animal Type
Falcon Captive      390.0
       Wild         350.0
       overall      390.0
Parrot Captive       30.0
       Wild          20.0
       overall       30.0
```

How can I do it?

The reason for adding the sub-level-row, is that it enables choosing category when I put it into BI tools for other colleagues.

UPDATE: in the example above I show using `max()`, I also want to know how to do it with `user_id.nunique()`.

---

Right now I produce the result by 2 groupby and then concat them. something like

```
df1 = df.groupby(['animal', 'type'])['speed'].max()
df2 = df.groupby(['animal'])['speed'].max()
##### ...  manually add `overall` index to df_2
df_total = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()
```

but it seems bit too manual, is there better approach?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with 2 `concat`'s, starting from your `groupby` result.

---

```
g = df.groupby(level=0).max()

m = pd.concat([g], keys=['overall'], names=['Type']).swaplevel(0, 1)

pd.concat([df, m], axis=0).sort_index(level=0)
```

```
                Max Speed
Animal Type
Falcon Captive      390.0
       Wild         350.0
       overall      390.0
Parrot Captive       30.0
       Wild          20.0
       overall       30.0
```

Comment: What if I use something like `.nunique()` as aggregate method, will this approach still valid?

Answer (score 1):

Adapting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41384950/4895877):

```py
# Create data
np.random.seed(2019)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'animal' : np.repeat(['Falcon', 'Parrot'], 10),
    'type' : np.tile(['Captive','Wild'], 10),
    'speed' : np.random.uniform(10,20,20)})
df.loc[df['animal'] == 'Falcon', 'speed'] = df['speed'] * 3
df.loc[df['type'] == 'Captive', 'speed'] = df['speed'] * .7

# Summary table
table = df.pivot_table(index=['animal','type'], values='speed', aggfunc=max)
# or... table = df.groupby(['animal','type'])['speed'].max().to_frame()

pd.concat([d.append(d.max().rename((k, 'Total')))
           for k, d in table.groupby(level=0) 
          ]).append(table.max().rename(('Grand','Total')))
```

gives

```
                    speed
animal type              
Falcon Captive  39.973127
       Wild     57.096185
       Total    57.096185
Parrot Captive  10.167126
       Wild     19.847235
       Total    19.847235
Grand  Total    57.096185
```

If you don't want the grand total, you can remove `.append(table.max().rename(('Grand','Total')))`

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way is :

```
df1 = df.groupby(['animal', 'type'])['speed'].max()

pd.concat([df1.reset_index(level='type'), pd.DataFrame(df1.max(level=0)).assign(
    type='overall')]).set_index('type',append=True).sort_index(level=0)
```

Out:

```
               speed
animal type              
Falcon Captive  19.238636
       Wild     19.607617
       overall  19.607617
Parrot Captive  18.386352
       Wild     17.735187
       overall  18.386352
```

Comment: What if I use something like .nunique() as aggregate method, is this approach still valid?

Comment: it should work as well. In general, any aggregation works.