# pandas multi index sort with several conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below,

```
  MATERIALNAME CURINGMACHINE  HEADERCOUNTER
0         1015        PPU03R           1529
1         3005        PPY12L            305
2         3005        PPY12R            359
3         3005        PPY12R            404
4         K843       PPZB06L            435
5         K928        PPZ03L           1850
```

I created a pivot table from this df,

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['MATERIALNAME', 'CURINGMACHINE'],
                       values = ['HEADERCOUNTER'],
                       aggfunc = 'count', fill_value = 0)
pivot    
(output)
                        HEADERCOUNTER
MATERIALNAME CURINGMACHINE               
1015         PPU03R                     1
3005         PPY12L                     1
             PPY12R                     2
K843         PPZB06L                    1
K928         PPZ03L                     1
```

I add subtotals of each material name with the help of this post 'pandas.concat' [Pivot table subtotals in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383302/pivot-table-subtotals-in-pandas)

```
pivot = pd.concat([
    d.append(d.sum().rename((k, 'Total')))
    for k, d in pivot.groupby(level=0)
]).append(pivot.sum().rename(('Grand', 'Total')))
```

My final df is,

```
                            HEADERCOUNTER
MATERIALNAME CURINGMACHINE               
1015         PPU03R                     1
             Total                      1
3005         PPY12L                     1
             PPY12R                     2
             Total                      3
K843         PPZB06L                    1
             Total                      1
K928         PPZ03L                     1
             Total                      1
Grand        Total                      6
```

I want to sort according to 'HEADERCOUNTER' column. I' m using this code,

```
sorted_df = pivot.sort_values(by =['HEADERCOUNTER'], ascending = False)
```

When I sort it, 'MATERIALNAME' column is effecting like below, 'MATERIALNAME' is broken as you can see from 3005 code.

```
                            HEADERCOUNTER
MATERIALNAME CURINGMACHINE               
Grand        Total                      6
3005         Total                      3
             PPY12R                     2
1015         PPU03R                     1
             Total                      1
3005         PPY12L                     1
K843         PPZB06L                    1
             Total                      1
K928         PPZ03L                     1
             Total                      1
```

When I sort it, I want to see in that order;

```
                            HEADERCOUNTER
MATERIALNAME CURINGMACHINE               
Grand        Total                      6
3005         Total                      3
             PPY12R                     2
             PPY12L                     1
1015         PPU03R                     1
             Total                      1
K843         PPZB06L                    1
             Total                      1
K928         PPZ03L                     1
             Total                      1
```

If you have any suggestions to change process, I can try it also.

**Edit:**
I tried **BENY**'s way, but it doesn' t work when data increases.

You can see the not ok result below;

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fix it by adding `argsort`

```
pivot = pivot.sort_values('HEADERCOUNTER',ascending=False)
out = pivot.iloc[(-pivot.groupby(level=0)['HEADERCOUNTER'].transform('max')).argsort()]
Out[136]: 
                            HEADERCOUNTER
MATERIALNAME CURINGMACHINE               
Grand        Total                      6
3005         Total                      3
             PPY12R                     2
             PPY12L                     1
1015         PPU03R                     1
             Total                      1
K843         PPZB06L                    1
             Total                      1
K928         PPZ03L                     1
             Total                      1
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It worked for this data but when data increases it doesn't work. It divides 'MATERIALNAME' again like i mentioned in question.