# Pandas Pivot Table - Adding Subtotals to Multiindex Table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a table of data structured as it follows:

| Name | Card | Payment ID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | t077 | 7312637 | 54 |
| John Doe | t077 | 1323131 | 34 |
| Jane Doe | s044 | 1231321 | 13 |
| John Doe | j544 | 4634564 | 53 |

The output I want to achieve is to have a pivot table with a similar format:

| Name | Number of Transactions | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 3 | 141 |
| --- t077 | 2 | 88 |
| --- j544 | 1 | 53 |
| Jane Doe | 1 | 13 |
| --- s044 | 1 | 13 |

Please keep in mind that:

- Payment ID uniquely identifies the transaction (every line in the table)
- Every Name can have one or multiple transactions with one or multiple cards

I tried using pandas pivot_table, however I cannot find a way to structure the data as I want (including subtotals per Name), I can only group by Name and Card using

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='Amount', index=['Name','Card'], aggfunc=(np.sum, len))
```

Sorry for the poor formatting on the table, my markdown skills are quite limited.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table is a good approach, try:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(
    df, 
    values=['Amount'],
    index=['Name', 'Card'],
    aggfunc=['count', 'sum'],
)

# Adds subtotals, and sorts:
pd.concat([
    d.append(d.sum().rename((k, 'Total')))
    for k, d in table.groupby(level=0)
]).sort_index(ascending=[False, True])
```

Output:

```
                count    sum
               Amount Amount
Name     Card
Joe Doe  Total      3    141
         j544       1     53
         t077       2     88
Jane Doe Total      1     13
         s044       1     13
```

Subtotal reference: [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383302/pivot-table-subtotals-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to create a `pivot_table` with `margins=True` and then use the function below:

```py
def pivot_table_w_subtotals(df, values, indices, columns, aggfunc, fill_value):
    '''
    Adds tabulated subtotals to pandas pivot tables with multiple hierarchical indices.
    
    Args:
    - df - dataframe used in pivot table
    - values - values used to aggregrate
    - indices - ordered list of indices to aggregrate by
    - columns - columns to aggregrate by
    - aggfunc - function used to aggregrate (np.max, np.mean, np.sum, etc)
    - fill_value - value used to in place of empty cells
    
    Returns:
    -flat table with data aggregrated and tabulated
    
    '''
    listOfTable = []
    for indexNumber in range(len(indices)):
        n = indexNumber+1
        if n == 1:
            table = pd.pivot_table(df,values=values,index=indices[:n],columns=columns,aggfunc=aggfunc,fill_value=fill_value,margins=True,observed=True)
        else:
            table = pd.pivot_table(df,values=values,index=indices[:n],columns=columns,aggfunc=aggfunc,fill_value=fill_value,observed=True)
        table = table.reset_index()
        for column in indices[n:]:
            table[column] = ''
        listOfTable.append(table)
    concatTable = pd.concat(listOfTable).sort_index()
    concatTable = concatTable.set_index(keys=indices)
    return concatTable.sort_index(axis=0,ascending=True)
```

Use example:

```py
pivot_table_w_subtotals(df=df_pivot,values=['Value1','Value2'],indices=['Store','Department','Type'],columns=[],aggfunc='sum',fill_value='')
```

Note: I added the following into the code on both of the `table =` lines:

```py
,observed=True
```

([source](https://towardsdatascience.com/tabulating-subtotals-dynamically-in-python-pandas-pivot-tables-6efadbb79be2))

I am in the process of modifying this a little bit, as I have a `dCategorical` sort that is present in the original `df_pivot` but not in the returned table. Any help would be great!