# Pandas - Adding Subtotals to Multiindex Table

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have created a multi-index table in pandas and now want to add a subtotal for each 'first' index.
My indexes are structured as: Geographical area, country, company, project.

I found this line of code here in stack overflow:

```
pd.concat([
    d.append(d.sum().rename((k, 'Total')))
    for k, d in table.groupby(level=0)
]).sort_index(ascending=[False, True])
```

It works, but for some reason it only works if I have 3 indices (i.e. if I remove the project column). If I leave all 4 indices, python only gives me one index: all 4 in brackets. Does this mean that there is some kind of limitation? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What would be useful is if you added some input data as well as expected output.

Comment: For each geographical area I have a number of countries and for each country a customer and for each customer a total. Something like:

Europe; IT; Telecom; Project ID; Total
             IT; Wind; Project ID; Total

The output should be

Europe; Subtotal
             IT; Telecom; Project ID; Total
             IT; Wind; Project ID; Total

If I try to use the Python code I posted instead I get:
(Europe, IT, Telecom, Project, Total) in brackets as the only index and then the total

Comment: Check out this solution from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75902670/16054911